# Setting up read-only Azure database, allow open access

Tags: azure-sql-database

I need to set up a training database on Azure that will allow all users to run Select statements (nothing else, it will be read-only).

Multiple users would all be logging in as the same read-only login, and creating/running select statements via SSMS or some other tool.

Any caveats to doing this? I'm planning on opening up the firewall and allowing all IP addresses to access it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AdventureWorkLT database that you can install from Azure portal as shown [here](http://www.sqlcoffee.com/Azure_0004.htm).

Take in consideration that Basic tier only allows 300 sessions and 30 concurrent logins. You may have to use Standard tiers depending on the number of sessions expected. Please visit [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-resource-limits) documentation for more information about limits of Azure SQL tiers.